# similar elements in HashMap and List

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have `ArrayList<Integer> L1` and `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> L`
which contain boolean numbers `[0.1]`. I want to increment my counter if `values=1`, but my code increments for both 0 and 1.

### My Code

```
 public static HashMap sim(HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> 
 L,ArrayList<Integer> L1){
    System.out.println("HASHMAP SIMILIRATE RESULT:");
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> sim = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    int count;
    int k = 0;


    for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> e : L.entrySet()) {

        count = 0;
        //you can move this part to another method to avoid deep nested code
        for (Integer mapValue : e.getValue()) {

            if (mapValue.equals(L1.get(k++))) {

                count =count+1;

            }
            else{

            }
        }
        sim.put(e.getKey(), count);
        k=0;

    }
    System.out.println(sim);
    return(sim);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I find your question unclear, I think you want to compare a key's value (a list) to the `L1` list and count the amount of times they both have value 1 set for the same index.

Replace:

```
if (mapValue.equals(L1.get(k++))) {
}
```

with

```
if (mapValue == 1 && mapValue.equals(L1.get(k++))) {
}
```